# How do JOINs distribute over OUTER JOINs?

Tags: sql, join

Are there any case where these two are not equivalent?

```
A OUTER JOIN (B JOIN C)
A OUTER JOIN C OUTER JOIN B
```

Comment: Yes. E.g. if b join c has no matches.

Comment: @jarlh: Oops, see my update

Comment: "outerjoin" is not a SQL operation.  There is `left outer join`, `right outer join`, and `full outer join`.  They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

In your first example (`A OUTERJOIN (B JOIN C)`), if either B or C does not have a matching record, both B and C are omitted.

In your second example (`A OUTERJOIN C OUTERJOIN B`), C can be returned even if B does not have a matching record.

Answer (score 0):

Still same as my comment. If B join C produces an empty result set, then A outer join "empty result set" is the same as just A.

A outer join B outer join C is something different (as least if one of B and C are not empty.)

Answer (score 0):

Since A seems to connect to C, it would be clearer to write the first option as:

```
A OUTERJOIN (C JOIN B)
```

The key difference between your two options is whether data from C is returned when there is a match between A and C.  Just looking at this aspect the two options could be viewed as the sets:

```
intersect(A,intersect(C,B))
intersect(A,C)
```

Clearly, the two are different since the first form can eliminate rows from C before it is intersected with A.

Answer (score 0):

What fields you join on can  make a difference as tables are not guaranteed to have only one possible field to join to another table on. And in this case does table b have a field to join to either table c or table a? That makes a differnce. What fields you want returned make a difference to the results set and whther two things will return the same results. The state of the data makes a differnce as some queries will appear to be equivalent until the data changes. SO understnding that these are not equivalent queires helps you avoid these mistakes. Whether you use a full, left or right outer join makes a difference as well. And finally what where clauses you add can make a differnce in whther they appear to be equivalent.

Check out these examples using temp tables (SQL server syntax)

```
create table #a (aid int, sometext varchar(50))
create table #b (bid int, sometext2 varchar(50), cid int, aid int)
create table #c (cid int, sometext3 varchar(50),  aid int)

insert into #a 
values(1, 'test') , (2, 'test2'), (3, 'test3')

insert into #b 
values(1, 'test', 1, 2) , (2, 'test2', 2, 1), (3, 'test3', 2, 2)

insert into #c 
values(1, 'test', 1) , (2, 'test2', 2), (3, 'test3', 1)


select * 
from  #a a
left outer join #c c  on a.aid = c.aid
left outer join #b b on a.aid = b.aid

select * 
from  #a a
left outer join #c  c on a.aid = c.aid
left outer join #b  b on c.cid = b.cid

select *
from #a a
left outer join #b b 
join #c c on b.cid = c.cid
on a.aid = b.aid

select * 
from  #a a
right outer join #c c  on a.aid = c.aid
right outer join #b b on a.aid = b.aid

select * 
from  #a a
right outer join #c  c on a.aid = c.aid
right outer join #b  b on c.cid = b.cid

select *
from #a a
right outer join #b b 
join #c c on b.cid = c.cid
on a.aid = b.aid

select * 
from  #a a
full outer join #c c  on a.aid = c.aid
full outer join #b b on a.aid = b.aid

select * 
from  #a a
full outer join #c  c on a.aid = c.aid
full outer join #b  b on c.cid = b.cid

select *
from #a a
full outer join #b b 
join #c c on b.cid = c.cid
on a.aid = b.aid
```